# Replace Vuetify timeline circle with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How to replace the [Vuetify timeline circle](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/timelines#timelines) that indicates a new timeline entry with a [Vuetify checkbox](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#checkboxes-boolean)?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-timeline>
      <v-timeline-item>timeline item</v-timeline-item>
    </v-timeline>

    <!-- Checkbox 
<v-checkbox v-model="checkbox1" :label="`Checkbox 1: ${checkbox1.toString()}`">
-->

  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use slot as follows :

```
 <v-timeline-item color="transparent">
       <template v-slot:icon>
                <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox1" :label="checked">
        </template>  
      </v-timeline-item>
```

You need some CSS to center the checkbox inside `v-timeline-item`, however i recommend to use [`v-stepper`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers#vertical-multi-line-error-state) component